# Unable to install App on real device or distribute it ad hoc, normal on Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, signing, ios16, xcode14

Running on the simulator works fine, but when I try to run on an iPhone using a USB cable, Xcode says:

`A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.`

Both the app and simulator are running iOS 16.

- Xcode 14.1
- Latest Cocoapod and ruby

The message in the picture says something about the profile but I'm not able/know how to add/upgrade it.

[image]

```
    Unable to install "Runner"
    Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
    Code: -402620395
    User Info: {
        DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-12-07 17:43:42 +0000";
        IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    }
    --
    A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
    Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
    Code: -402620395
    User Info: {
        DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
        MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008015)";
        "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
        0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010d3afc90 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 235
        1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010d3ec2ee __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
        2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102e4ac71 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
        3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010d3ec016 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1409
        4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010d0cd780 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3520
        5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102f80879 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
        6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102f8138d __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 196
        7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff8016577fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff801658a44 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80165eac4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 694
        10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80165f5b4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff801669ad7 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 762
        12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8017d4ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 326
        13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8017d3c67 start_wqthread + 15
    );
    }
    --
    
    Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
        "device_model" = "iPhone8,2";
        "device_osBuild" = "15.7.1 (19H117)";
        "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
        "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
        "launchSession_state" = 1;
        "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
        "operation_duration_ms" = 14739;
        "operation_errorCode" = "-402620395";
        "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
        "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
        "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
        "param_consoleMode" = 0;
        "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
        "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
        "param_debugger_type" = 5;
        "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
        "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
        "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
        "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
        "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
        "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
        "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
        "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
        "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
        "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
        "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
        "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
        "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
        "param_install_style" = 0;
        "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
        "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
        "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
        "param_launcher_style" = 0;
        "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
        "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
        "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
        "param_runnable_type" = 2;
        "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
        "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
        "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
        "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.1";
        "sdk_osVersion" = "16.1";
        "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
    }
    --
    
    
    System Information
    
    macOS Version 13.0.1 (Build 22A400)
    Xcode 14.1 (21534.1) (Build 14B47b)
    Timestamp: 2022-12-07T18:43:42+01:00
```

Comment: Please post the text of the error instead of an image - makes it easier for people using screenreaders and dark mode.

Comment: Just iserted the full text error. Same error on another iPhone running iOS 15.7.1. It is impossible to install due to the previous error.

Comment: Running on the simulator doesn't require a provisioning profile. Running on a real device does. Have you logged into your AppleID in Xcode settings?  Once you have done that set the signing to "automatic" and try again.